# Checking cache control max age setting in firefox

Tags: http, firefox, http-headers, browser-cache

Firefox has a cool feature which allows me to check the cache.

I simple type

```
about:cache
```

in the address bar and some useful cache information appears. This includes every file cached and its expires time.  However, I don't know if firefox is getting this information from the expires header or the cache control header or just obeying HTTP 1.1 which states that if both are set the cachc control max age header wins?

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is just following HTTP 1.1 here: max-age, then expires, then the suggested heuristic, in that order.